# Error Handling for Multiple DAG Creation in a Single Python File

Tags: python, airflow

I'm currently facing an issue with creating two DAGs within the same Python file. When one of the DAGs encounters an error, neither of the DAGs is displayed on the Airflow interface upon uploading the file. However, I would like the functioning DAG (FIRST_DAG on my example below) to be visible and available for use in Airflow, even if the other DAG encounters an error.

Here is an example of the code structure, in this example the SECOND_DAG will raise an error because of an operator that was not defined:

```
with models.DAG("FIRST_DAG") as dag:

    first_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='first_operator')
    second_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='second_operator')
    first_operator >> second_operator

with models.DAG("SECOND_DAG") as dag:

    first_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='first_operator')
    second_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='second_operator')

    first_operator >> second_operator >> THIS_WILL_TRIGGER_AN_ERROR
```

I would gladly accept any insights of how can I, if possible, show the error on the airflow interface (as it is happening when I upload this file) but also keep the functioning dag (FIRST_DAG) to be used on airflow.